# Server Generated web screenshots?

Tags: web-services

One problem I've been toying with off and on is a service that requires my server to produce a screenshot of a webpage at a given url. The problem is that I don't have any idea how I would accomplish this. I mostly use a LAMP software stack, so answers that were given with that in mind would be the most helpful. Again the basic requirements are: Given a url, the server needs to produce an image file of the rendered web page at that url. Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't worry traumaPony, my web service has nothing to do with pop up images that hover over links while you're trying to read an article :)

Answer (score 6):

You might also want to take a look at [webkit](http://webkit.org/), it's known for being easier to embed (used by Adobe for AIR, by Google for Chrome, by Apple for the iPhone...) then other rendering engines. This might take a little more work to setup, but it would be a lot more stable than some hack that launched a webbrowser and took a screenshot.

Comment: Nowadays there is available [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/), a headless WebKit.

Comment: @jholster Thanks for this comment! PhantomJS looks exactly like what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

**IF** your server is a **Mac**, then I recommend [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/), which is a short python program that leverages WebKit's Objective-C API to render an URL. Personally, I use it in combination with [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/) to walk my development site and make screenshots of every page -- useful for testing functionality, showing clients and keeping screenshots up-to-date. The resulting screenshot is perfect, but sometimes very tall for long, scrolling pages.

**IF** your server has a non-bare-bones **Linux** distro with KDE installed, then you might try [khtml2png](http://www.babysimon.co.uk/khtml2png/index.html). I have not tried that myself, but saw it mentioned on the webkit2png page.

Comment: Somehow I don't think there are that many Mac servers out there, but khtml2png looks good too (if not as polished)

Answer (score 3):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless (commandline) WebKit-based browser which can be easily [scripted](http://pielmeier.blogspot.fi/2011/02/headless-html-page-rendering-with.html) to save a screenshot of webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to have the server launch the web browser in question and take a screenshot of the application with the appropriate libraries. Apache will not render the page for you so you have to have software that will.

Comment: right. A couple of ideas that I had were to actually automatically collect a screenshot from the desktop environment, or somehow use the gecko engine to build a rendered version of the page that I could build an image from. Hmm....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is what is needed. I do this in asp.net, and I actually create a WebBrowser object that is avaialable in the .Net framework class libraries to generate the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I use the http://webthumb.bluga.net service for thumbnail generation.  Robust, powerful, easy to use, and very reasonable rates.  I have a high traffic production website using this service and it works very well.  Given the difficulty of creating a robust web screenshot service, it's nice to have someone else do the hard work.

Comment: but it does not capture an entire website, it just thumbnails it.

Answer (score 0):

A non-free solution for Java is [WebRenderer](http://www.webrenderer.com/).  Interesting feature: it can emulate Safari, IE or Firefox browsers when rendering.  They have a desktop version and a headless server version.  Also they have example code showing how to render a screenshot image of a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

> virtual framebuffer X server

I would rather recommend [XVFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) (virtual framebuffer X server) is the best solution for taking screenshots of a headless server.  Virtual framebuffer X server xvfb provides an X server that can run on machines with no display hardware and no physical input devices. 
I am using that on my server for testing URLs and taking its screenshot. We are using Ubuntu & XVFB + FIREFOX. It is working fine. Modify according to your needs.Take a look on these articles. It might be use full for you.

http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html

http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/xvfb.htm

http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html