# Are there any free ways to turn an html page into an image with .net

Tags: .net, rendering, screenshot, html

I want to take html, including the text and images and turn it into one image containing everything.  Is there a free way to do it?

This is using .net 3.5.

#### See also:

[Server Generated web screenshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119116/server-generated-web-screenshots)
[What is the best way to create a web page thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65078/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-web-page-thumbnail)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might check out [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/IECapture.aspx) or [this page](http://www.developerfusion.co.uk/show/4712/).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code that I posted on my blog a few weeks ago that does this:

[C#: Generate WebPage Thumbnail Screenshot Image](http://pietschsoft.com/post.aspx?id=2a628f30-fe83-4e44-a34b-f31be76d1b4f)

I'll also post the code for it below:

```
public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url)
{
    // This method gets a screenshot of the webpage
    // rendered at its full size (height and width)
    return GenerateScreenshot(url, -1, -1);
}

public Bitmap GenerateScreenshot(string url, int width, int height)
{
    // Load the webpage into a WebBrowser control
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    wb.Navigate(url);
    while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) { Application.DoEvents(); }


    // Set the size of the WebBrowser control
    wb.Width = width;
    wb.Height = height;

    if (width == -1)
    {
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full width
        wb.Width = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
    }

    if (height == -1)
    {
        // Take Screenshot of the web pages full height
        wb.Height = wb.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
    }

    // Get a Bitmap representation of the webpage as it's rendered in the WebBrowser control
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(wb.Width, wb.Height);
    wb.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, wb.Width, wb.Height));
    wb.Dispose();

    return bitmap;
}
```

Here's some example usages:

```
// Generate thumbnail of a webpage at 1024x768 resolution
Bitmap thumbnail = GenerateScreenshot("http://pietschsoft.com", 1024, 768);

// Generate thumbnail of a webpage at the webpage's full size (height and width)
thumbnail = GenerateScreenshot("http://pietschsoft.com");

// Display Thumbnail in PictureBox control
pictureBox1.Image = thumbnail;

/*
// Save Thumbnail to a File
thumbnail.Save("thumbnail.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
*/
```