# Open source Java library to produce webpage thumbnails server-side

Tags: java, open-source, thumbnails

I am searching for an open source Java library to generate thumbnails for a given URL.  I need to bundle this capability, rather than call out to external services, such as [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ast/) or [websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/).

http://www.webrenderer.com/ was mentioned in this post: [Server generated web screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119116/server-generated-web-screenshots#119264), but it is a commercial solution.

I'm hoping for a Java based solution, but may need to look into executing an external process such as [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=faq), or integrating something like [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is using AWT to capture a screen grab (see code below). You could look at capturing the [JEditorPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html), the [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/) [WebBrowser](https://jdic.dev.java.net/nonav/documentation/javadoc/jdic/org/jdesktop/jdic/browser/package-summary.html) control or the [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) [Browser](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/package-summary.html) (via the [AWT embedding support](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/awt/package-summary.html)). The latter two embed native browsers (IE, Firefox), so introduce dependencies; the JEditorPane HTML support stopped at HTML 3.2. It may be that none of these will work on a headless system.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Capture {

    private static final int WIDTH = 128;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 128;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    public void capture(Component component) {
        component.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        try {
            component.paint(g);
        } finally {
            g.dispose();
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage getScaledImage(int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = buffer.createGraphics();
        try {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        } finally {
            g.dispose();
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    public void save(File png, int width, int height) throws IOException {
        ImageIO.write(getScaledImage(width, height), "png", png);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Hello, World!");
        label.setOpaque(true);

        Capture cap = new Capture();
        cap.capture(label);
        cap.save(new File("foo.png"), 64, 64);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can save and grab the whole site and use this lib to generate a thumbnail for HTML: https://github.com/makbn/JThumbnail

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially asking for a complete rendering engine accessible by Java. Personally, I would save myself the hassle and call out to a child process.

Otherwise, I ran into this pure Java browser: [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

wasn't there a QA/test website/service which would let you specify a web page that you wanted to be rendered in a certain browser(IE, FIREFOX, SAFARI version x,y,z) and they would mail the snapshot back to you. '

I can't remember the service -- maybe other developers who frequent ajaxian might remember it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). I know it's not a Java solution, but you can call it from Java, and there's even a [Java front-end](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/), although I've had less success with that.