# Are there any java library for thumbnails generation?

Tags: java, thumbnails

I need some smart enough thumbnail generation lib to use it in my java app. I've found appropriate code [here](http://www.philreeve.com/java_high_quality_thumbnails.php) but I'm not sure about possible licensing issues.

Are there any free appropriate libraries?

Comment: Did you contact the author to see if there were licensing issues?

Comment: Java thumbnail generator for Office,PDF,HTML,Text,MP3,MPEG and Image documents

 https://github.com/makbn/JThumbnail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you split the task "create thumbnail" into three steps, "load image", "scale image" and "save image", you can do it with the standard Java API. You can use the static utility methods in `javax.imageio.ImageIO` to load and save images and use `Image#getScaledInstance(...)` to resize the original image. Since the `Image` you get from `getScaledInstance` is not a `BufferedImage`, you have to create a new `BufferedImage` with the correct size and paint the scaled image into the new `BufferedImage` before you can use ImageIO to save it.

Answer (score 24):

Try thumbnailator: http://code.google.com/p/thumbnailator/. All the code you need to add is:

```
Thumbnails.of(new File("path/to/directory").listFiles())
    .size(640, 480)
    .outputFormat("jpg")
    .toFiles(Rename.PREFIX_DOT_THUMBNAIL);
```

It's also fast: https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/wiki/Comparison

Good luck

Comment: love it! works like a charm and super easy to use. plugged into my website within minutes and am very happy with this

Comment: For easy integration with popular build tools see: [http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.coobird/thumbnailator](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.coobird/thumbnailator)

Answer (score 2):

For creating thumbnails using API methodology, Scalr.resize("your arguments") would be the best one.
Also thumbanilator is an option where you dont have to waste much time of yours in understanding, just call the respective method and enjoy with your output thumbnail.
Performance/Quality wise Scalr is best.
Quality wise thumbnailator is ok.

Answer (score 0):

There is [jmagick](http://www.jmagick.org/), a Java Implementation of the popular ImageMagick framework.

Comment: Good idea, but suboptimal. Adding an external dependency and calling native methods via an ABI wrapper is not what a Java developer calls good solution.

Comment: It's not really a Java implementation, it's a Java interface to the native ImageMagick libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked his site and there's no mention of license. That could mean trouble. At least in Italy where I live because if there's no explicit permission you can't use works that are not yours.

I would suggest to read this question: [Open source Java library to produce webpage thumbnails server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169573/open-source-java-library-to-produce-webpage-thumbnails-server-side)