# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

Tags: java, javacv, javacpp

I am using Windows10, eclipse-neon with JDK1.8 version,
I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:385)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2719)
at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:391)
at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:385)
at com.segment.processor.AudioMain.main(ApacheMathAudioMain.java:20)
Error getting static method ID of org/bytedeco/javacpp/Loader/putMemberOffset
```

here are the dependencies I am using in  my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>ffmpeg</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2-1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0-1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I recommended to use OpenCV which has a good Java wrapper instead of JavaCV.

Comment: Check the jar files to see whether they contain the class e.g jar tf [jarfile] | grep org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

Comment: removed JavaCV and used OpenCV dependency but still getting the same exception

Comment: I have opened all the available jars like `javacpp-0.10, javacpp-1.2.2, opencv-3.1.0-1.2, javacv-1.1` etc but none of them contains `avutil` class.
Where it is available actually.. I mean in which dependency

Comment: update this dependency to <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>0.10</version>
    </dependency>  1.4.1.

Comment: It would be good if you'd include a minimal and complete `pom.xml` and `main` class that reproduces this error. There are some issues with the dependencies in your pom (see my answer), but without a complete example we are all basically fishing in the dark, as there could be more issues with your project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First problem**

Your versions don't match. `org.bytedeco.javacpp` in version `0.10` is from *Dec 2014*, while all your other versions are from *May 2016*. You need to use version `1.2` of `org.bytedeco.javacpp`, or better yet, update all dependencies to the latest version.

You can see the versions here:

[org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets » opencv](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv)

[org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets » ffmpeg](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg)

[org.bytedeco » javacv](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv)

[org.bytedeco » javacpp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacpp)

**Second problem**

You include the dependencies for Java code only, but you don't include the dependencies for native code (both opencv and ffmpeg are native libraries). You need to include `opencv-platform` and `ffmpeg-platform` instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1-1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2-1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This will make Maven download and include opencv and ffmpeg libraries for Android, Linux, MacOS and Windows, both x86 and x64.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil

Actual cause of error is different versions of dependencies. That's why `javacpp` package failed during mapping of classes.

Follow these step to resolve this problem:

- Download latest version of Javacv library package from [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/releases)
- Copy these three `.jar` files into `libs` folder

  - `ffmpeg.jar`
  - `javacv.jar`
  - `javacpp.jar`
- Create `jniLibs` folder in `app\src\main`
- Now, create four different folders for different architectures

  - `arm64-v8a`
  - `armeabi`
  - `armeabi-v7a`
  - `x86`
- Change extension of these two files `ffmpeg-android-arm.jar, ffmpeg-android-x86.jar` to `.zip` then unzip both folders and Copy `.so` files for each architecture and paste in its respected directory. Your resultant directory should be look like this
- [image: List item]
- Add `.jar` dependencies in your gradle file as follows:

  ````
  implementation files('libs/ffmpeg.jar')
  implementation files('libs/javacpp.jar')
  implementation files('libs/javacv.jar')```
  ````

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the dependencies with the latest versions and check whether class exists in that or not

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv/1.4.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/3.4.2-1.4.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/3.4.1-1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This means that the class is there at compiletime but missing at runtime. You have a couple of options:

- Always execute with a Maven plugin.
- Include the library in the classpath when running.
- Use the Maven Shade plugin to make an Uber-Jar which includes dependencies.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I am sorry for downvoting your answer, as I don't want to discourage a new user from contributing to the platform, but in this particular case your answer is unfortunately wrong. The Java class is definitely there, it just can't be initialized by the JVM because it relies on native code, and that native code wasn't included as dependency.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me! How did you know that the dependency relied on native code?

Comment: Because it does? It's a direct wrapper of native code. Just look at the [source](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/blob/master/ffmpeg/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacpp/avutil.java).