# Use a HTML page as Live Wallpaper in Android

Tags: android, web, live-wallpaper

Can I use a HTML page as a Live Wallpaper?
Or is it possible to capture a web page as an image and set it as a wallpaper?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an app on the market called [WebLiveWallpaper](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dngames.websitelivewallpaper&feature=search_result) that does this. There is an option in it for how often to refresh the view of the web page, which leads me to believe that it is simply taking a snapsnot of the page and presenting it as an image some how. Unfortunately I wouldn't know how to go about setting that up. But I think you're definitely going to want to go the image route.

Edit Here are some links that may help you out:

[Open source Java library to produce webpage thumbnails server-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169573/open-source-java-library-to-produce-webpage-thumbnails-server-side)

http://www.acasystems.com/en/web-thumb-activex/

http://www.fileguru.com/apps/convert_html_to_image_in_java

I have not used any of these components before so I'm not positive about them but they seem like they can do what your looking for .

Comment: thanks Mr Tim.. but i need some code reference about it.. if u have some code references plz share with me...

Answer (score 7):

I am the author of the mentioned WebLiveWallpaper. It can use both techniques: Showing a web snapshot from snapr, webthumb, ... but normally it is really a WebView which has disadvantages but also some advantages. A web snapshot/thumb image cannot update animated images fast enough. But it avoids the problems a 'hacked' WebView in a live wallpaper has (like missing images, huge memory footprint).

I think what you want is using one of these:
http://www.websnapr.com/
http://webthumb.bluga.net/home
http://snapr.seekxl.de

They all have more and better documentation on their sites than I can put in here. Mostly it is simply a picture from their url with your key and some settings.

Comment: Sadly web live wallpaper is not available anymore.