# Creating images of website URLs in Java

Tags: java, thumbnails

I want to write my own service to create images of website URLs as done by [webshotspro](http://www.webshotspro.com) / [shrinktheweb](http://www.shrinktheweb.com/) and many other websites. Is there any Java based API available for this?

Comment: Have you looked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169573/open-source-java-library-to-produce-webpage-thumbnails-server-side

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write something like your own mini browser and catch the screen of your app for some site. It's easy can be done with integrated classes.