# How do they get this snapshot?

Tags: screenshot, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server Generated web screenshots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119116/server-generated-web-screenshots)

Whenever i use 
**goo.gl** to shorten urls
, i see a screenshot of the url's  page!

It's not usual screenshot - there're no UI elements - only the page itself!

My question: How do they do it? What is the general logic behind generating this screenshot(raster image)?

Comment: This might seem non-constructive comment, but have you googled it? It took me about couple of seconds to find an article called "15 ways to take a website screenshot" listing all sorts of software that can do that. If you are after the implementation, then what have you tried?

Comment: There are also a few related questions in the sidebar here on Stackoverflow. I don't think there is much "logic" behind it. They just render the page (headless and automated) into an image file.

Comment: @valentinas  no. i'm not after implementation. I'd like to get a  general idea how it's done! (and also, without using canvas element)

Answer (score 0):

> @valentinas no. i'm not after implementation. I'd like to get a
>   general idea how it's done! (and also, without using canvas element) –
>   DrStrangeLove 6 mins ago

General idea: you take a browser rendering engine (webkit is pretty good, here's one of the implementations: http://phantomjs.org/) and instead of outputting the result to UI you take it and dump it to file.